# Is it possible to deploy project in the Apache not in IIS (ASP.NET MVC WEB-API)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, apache, iis, asp.net-web-api, ubuntu-14.04

Is it possible to deploy project in the Apache not in IIS (ASP.NET MVC WEB-API), if yes , how to do . I have built Ubuntu with Apache. so that anyone who has any ideas or methods can help me, thanks.

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/ it is very clear that you need to configure mod_mono.

Comment: thanks , I will check this URL